# Static files on nginx reverse proxy not working

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have installed docker and nginx configured nginx on a machine that will be used for deploying small apps for inside testing.

I'm tring to redirect requests from a subfolder on the server
Example: dev.domain.com/glpi to a container on the same server with the ip: 192.168.10.5:3300
It displays the raw page, but static files are not being piped to the correct path, that would be dev.domain.com/glpi/static/xxx.js but are being redirected to dev.domain.com/static/xxx.js and getting 404 Not Found

nginx configuration file:

```
location /glpi {  
  proxy_pass http://192.168.10.5:3300/$1;  
  proxy_set_header Host $host;  
  proxy_set_head``er X-Real-IP $remote_addr;  
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
  proxy_set_header X-Script-Name /glpi;  
}
```

Static files should be on dev.domain.com/glpi/static/xxx.js but instead are being redirected to dev.domain.com/static/xxx.js and getting 404 error.